# FlowJs promise : Promise<any> view as Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, flowtype, typechecking

I have some issue with FlowJs and runtime TypeCheck, this is the issue

```
Expected:
Promise<any>

Got:
Promise {
  _bitField: number;
  _fulfillmentHandler0: void;
  _rejectionHandler0: void;
  _promise0: void;
  _receiver0: void;
}
```

I don't understand why ...
I use some Bluebird Promise.resolve in my code, maybe it's the problem?
Promise.resolve ... doesn't return the same object as javascript Promise...

How to manage that?

Comment: share your code

Comment: Thank you I found my Error I had to remove import Promise from 'bluebird' auto imported by webstorm